Looking to identify and find an equivalent varistor for a Crest ca9 amplifier
I picked up a Crest ca9 amplifier over the weekend knowing it needed work when I plugged it in And turned it on it. Started letting the smoke out. Long story short, I found a varistor That had blown. I've been scouring the internet trying to identify its specifications with little to no luck. There are few numbers on it 811-6 hopefully that means something to somebody. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you search for "Crest ca9 circuit diagram" you will find its service manual. Note that it has +/-122 V power rails, so don't touch anything without discharging the power supply capacitors first.

...although I couldn't see that side of the power supply in a diagram. Maybe this Q&A will be useful.

Thank you for your reply! That manual will be helpful. However I'm struggling to find a part number for the actual part I'm looking for it's just those 2 round resistor deals. They bother measure around 1.2 ohms roughly I think. Is there any other pictures I could take that would be helpful? Thanks!

Looks like it is called an inrush current limiter but I'm not sure what the specifications are for them

Did you see this answer in the Q&A I previously linked to? However, you need to know why it blew, so don't go connecting it to the mains again until you know that.

An inrush current limiter would be an NTC thermistor. Can you work out the circuit diagram for that part of the circuit? Photos of the entire PCB from both sides might help.
